# Insert array data in separate database row in a field not the same Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I am trying to insert an array data into the database, on form submit with the following input field **(Name, Age, Amount**) but I am getting **Array to string conversion** Error, so I added **json_encode()** to the variable to prevent the error, but the issue now is on insertion into the database, the array data is inserting the data in the same row, I want it in different row of same filed, see below image thanks

[image]

**B is the result I want to get**

**Controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

    $userid = rand(10000,99999);
    $username = $request->get('uname');
    $userage = json_encode($request->get('uage'));
    $useramount = json_encode($request->get('uamount');


    if (isset($username)){
        foreach ( $request->get('uname') as $username) {
            $add[] = [
                'user_id' => $userid,
                'user_name' => $username,
                'user_age' => $userage,
                'user_amount' => $useramount,
            ];
        }
        Person::insert($add);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

good morning, I hope I understand your problem correctly.
Your inputs need to look like this:

```
<input name="user[name]" />
<input name="user[age]" />
<input name="user[amount]" />
```

And its storage function as follows:

```
public function store(Request $request){
$userid = rand(10000,99999);
$user = $request->get('user');
if (isset($user)){
        Person::query()->create([
            'user_id' => $userid,
            'user_name' => $user['name'],
            'user_age' => $user['age'],
            'user_amount' => $user['amount'],
        ]);
}}
```

Comment: HI @Afshin Tavakolian, thanks for your respond, but it is only inserting one column to the database,  I have **clone** of the form input(Name, Age, Amount) I mean **TWO name, age, amount input form**, that is the reason for **foreach**

Comment: To do this, just change the name of the inputs as follows:
user[][name]
user[][age]
user[][amount]
And also the storage code snippet like this:
public function store(Request $request){
$userid = rand(10000,99999);
$users = $request->get('user');
if (isset($users)){
        foreach($users as $user){
Person::query()->create([
            'user_id' => $userid,
            'user_name' => $user['name'],
            'user_age' => $user['age'],
            'user_amount' => $user['amount'],
        ]);
     }
}}